# Trying to change property values of other methods?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

So I was making a to-do list app, and I had this variable inside VIEWDIDLOAD:

```
var edit = UIBarButtonItem (title: "Edit", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(editfunc))
```

I wanted that when someone finishes editing, the button changes from 'edit' to 'done' so I wrote this:

```
@objc func editfunc () {

    table.isEditing = !table.isEditing

    if table.isEditing == true {
        edit.title = "Done"
    }
    else {
        edit.title = "Edit"
    }
}
```

It didn't work. I googled it and it seems like the solution was to write **'var edit' outside of the viewdidload func**, and also to use **'lazy'** before it. It worked, but I still didn't understand why? What's the difference between defining properities inside and outside viewdidload and why did it work only when I used 'lazy'm, a

Comment: You can look up `scope` specifically local scope vs `class`/`struct` scope.https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html

Comment: Hello? Please!!

Comment: The answer is because of the scope of the variable. If you create it in a function it is only in scope for that function. If you create it outside of the function or in other words in the class’ scope it is available to the whole class. Read that link it will be a lot more explanatory.

Answer (score -1):

It's as Lorem ipsum commented that it's about the scope of the variable.

But to answer your second question about the `lazy` property is used on variables where you want to use `self` as `Lazy` waits for `init` to be run. `self` is still available as a property, but as `init` has not been run yet, you are basically asserting `nil` to the `target` property